# Get javascript data to the gwt side

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

I am using javascript variable which has json data like:

```
<script>var info = '${partyList}'</script>
```

I got the above string in my html like below:

```
var info = [{"tenantKey":"Demo:farcoahuja@gmail.com","lastModifiedDate":1407410632468,"seqId":1,"lastModifiedBy":"farcoahuja@gmail.com","historyStr":null,"mDate":null,"mBy":null,"partyOrgKey":"5488762045857792","id":6245226045767680,"organizationName":"","fullName":"ram's","partyNameSplitList":["ram"],"currencyId":6262818231812096,"currency":null,"comments":null,"panNo":"","tinNo":"","serviceTaxNo":"","internalRole":"CUSTOMER","acctgAttrib":{"mainBranch":false,"balance":0.0,"openingBalance":0.0,"finalBalance":0.0},"glAcctOrgKey":"4837851162214400:6245226045767680","priceListRef":null,"priceList":null,"mapFirstName":null,"mapLastName":null}];
```

If you see my above json key-value("fullName":"ram's"), the value ram's has a special character(single quote).
 I have got this to the gwt side by using JSNI.

```
private static native String getPartyListString() /*-{
     return $wnd.info;    
}-*/
```

The my above approach is correct but because of special single quotation in the value, the jsni was not able to get it to the gwt side.

How to get the above data to the gwt side?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `$wnd.partyList`, try returning `$wnd.info`. Since you named the JavaScript object `info` within your `<script>` tag, you need to call it by that in your JSNI method as well.

Comment: No, Here only i gave a wrong variable name but in my actual code it was correct, that's i edited my above code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting above is a JS object. If you want to fetch it like a string then you need to pass it to js object info like a string.
To do that :

```
<script>var info = "${partyList}";
var infoString = JSON.stringify(info);
</script>

private static native String getPartyListString() /*-{
     return $wnd.infoString;    
}-*/
```

Comment: Is it necessary to put JSON.stringfy(info), If i do like that my code does not work. Is my approach is wrong?

Comment: I am able to see it in 'View PageSource', but i could not get it to the gwt side

Comment: In actual GWT code you have put the return type of your native method as String so its neccessary to call JSON.stringify().

Comment: yes, it is right, i am getting null at gwt side, if i use that.

Comment: Can you open console on Chrome when on your GWT page with this script injected and type infoString and press enter. Can you share that output here.

Comment: I ran my app in the chrome, I got "ReferenceError: partyListInfo is not defined" in my console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58964/discussion-between-m-s-naidu-and-biplav).